# Bulma dropdown arrow isn't shown

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm currently struggling with the bulma navbar. This is my header:

```
 <header class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                    <span class="icon has-text-primary is-large">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-36px mdi-hexagon-multiple"></i>
                    </span>
                    <!-- <h1 class="title is-1">DNW</h1> -->
                </a>
                <span class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbarMenuHeroC">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-menu">
                <div class="navbar-end">
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Forum
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Spiele
                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-arrowless">
                        <div class="navbar-link">
                            <img class="nav-profilepic" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/1bfda4_6f8ae00a346644a89245f331fc6c6b8e~mv2_d_3476_5214_s_4_2.jpeg?dn=">
                            Tränenreich
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Profil
                            </a>
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Nachrichten
                            </a>

                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Rangliste
                            </a>
                            <hr class="navbar-divider">
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Hilfe
                            </a>
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Einstellungen
                            </a>
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Mod-Forum
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

The dropdown menu should show a blue arrow. But it doesn't show in Chrome nor in Firefox. Any ideas how to fix this?
[image]
I'd expect the output to show a dropdown arrow on the right next to "Tränenreich". Hovering works perfectly fine.

Greetings

Comment: what version of bulma you're using ? Try using CDN instead of a local file - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css and tell me how that goes.

Comment: `is-arrowless` in `<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-arrowless">` doesn't do anything, you can safely remove it. `is-arrowless` class is applied to the same element as `navbar-link` class does. Here's the docs on that - https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code combined with an unedited Bulma file is showing an arrow next to the dropdown item.  See demo below (you'll have to see full page perhaps because nav is changed to hamburger menu from tablet down).

My guess is either you've edited the Bulma CSS in a way that is breaking the arrow OR you have some custom CSS that is conflicting with it.

The arrow is created using a `:after` pseudo element.

```
.navbar-link:not(.is-arrowless)::after,
.select:not(.is-multiple):not(.is-loading)::after {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: .625em;
    margin-top: -.4375em;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    width: .625em;
}
```

Check your custom CSS to see if you have anything that is styling `:after` elements that is affecting the nav-item.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                    <span class="icon has-text-primary is-large">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-36px mdi-hexagon-multiple"></i>
                    </span>
                    <!-- <h1 class="title is-1">DNW</h1> -->
                </a>
                <span class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbarMenuHeroC">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-menu">
                <div class="navbar-end">
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Forum
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Spiele
                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-arrowless">
                        <div class="navbar-link">
                            <img class="nav-profilepic" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/1bfda4_6f8ae00a346644a89245f331fc6c6b8e~mv2_d_3476_5214_s_4_2.jpeg?dn=">
                            Tränenreich
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Profil
                            </a>
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Nachrichten
                            </a>

                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Rangliste
                            </a>
                            <hr class="navbar-divider">
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Hilfe
                            </a>
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Einstellungen
                            </a>
                            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Mod-Forum
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. The arrow in the `:after` pseudo element is styled as `border-color: transparent;`. Not surprising nothing is shown then. Is that the expected behavior?